# procedure & trigger postgresql add a condition doing it on only one line not all

Tags: postgresql

first I create a trigger and its procedure but procedure is missing a sub-statement in the if part

```
create trigger a_financereconnomiser after update of prix_reel on a_financer execute procedure payetoeconomie() ;
```

the procedure is currently that one :

```
create or replace function payetoeconomie() returns trigger as $$
begin
if (select prix_estim-prix_reel from a_financer) >= 1 then 
insert into  economie (ref,designation,economie ) select ref*1000,date,objet,prix_estim-prix_reel from a_financer where prix_reel ;
end if ; 
end $$
language 'plpgsql' ;
```

If I try here to use it, the psql answers the function returns more than a unique line
this seems logical

so I need to add a "***and that column as changed during the update***" on column
prix_reel. here is the thing I don't understand how to do it in the procedure.

for information tables are build like :

source one :

```
 ref        | integer          |                 | not null  |            | plain    |                       | 
 date       | date             |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 dl         | date             |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 prix_estim | integer          |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 prix_reel  | double precision |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 paye       | integer          |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 objet      | text             |                 |           |            | extended |                       | 
 besoin     | integer          |                 |           |            | plain    |                       |
```

and destination one as :

```
 ref         | integer          |                 | not null  |            | plain    |                       | 
 date        | date             |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 designation | text             |                 |           |            | extended |                       | 
 economie    | double precision |                 |           |            | plain    |                       | 
 commentaire | text             |                 |           |            | extended |                       |
```

Comment: Have a look e.g. at example 42.4 in the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpgsql-trigger.html), and use `NEW.objet` etc. for the fields, and something like `NEW.prix_reel != OLD.prix_reel` for the condition that the real price has changed, and put that in the `if` condition together with `NEW.prix_estim-NEW.prix_reel >= 1`. The way you are doing it you are not referring to the values that triggered the procedure at all. Also, return a NULL value at the end of the function (which gets ignored for `AFTER` triggers).

Comment: os so I did with it `............IF ec >= 1 THEN
    insert into  economie (ref,designation,economie) VALUES (NEW.ref*1000, NEW.objet, ec)...................`    & finished to found the good syntax for my needs.